# Are "volume contraction" lipschitz in some metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $\phi$ be a smooth map from a smooth compact surface $S$ (possibly with boundary) to $\mathbb{R}^n$, equipped with the euclidean metric. Suppose that $S$ is equipped with a volume form $\omega$, and that $|\phi^*(vol_{eucl})|\leq |\omega|$.

Does there exist a universal constant $K$ and a riemmannian metric $g$ on $S$ which induces $\omega$, and such that $\phi$ is $K$-Lipschitz? Can we take $K$ arbitrarily close to $1$? $K=1$?

Comment: I think, by "munished" you meant "equipped". In the modern slang, munished means "intoxicated" (e.g. "drunk").

Comment: I don't think so. A promising recipe for a counterexample would be to take two diffeos $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f'g'<1$ and consider the map $f\times g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with the euclidean metric on both $|mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Most likely, you can get $K=1$ and it even works when $S$ has higher dimension and the target space is some Riemannian manifold. I can write up a solution where you  get a continuous metric $g$, but to get higher order smoothness you would either settle for $K$ merely close to $1$ or deal with analysis issues yourself.

Comment: Indeed I meant equipped, thanks for correcting me :). If you could give me the proof (or at least explain it roughly) that would be nice! If you know how to add some smoothness at the cost of assuming $K>1$, I'd like to know that also :)